# Java out.println() how is this possible?

Tags: java, printing, libraries

I've seen some code such as:

```
out.println("print something");
```

I tried `import java.lang.System;`

but it's not working. How do you use `out.println()` ?

Answer (score 104, accepted):

static imports do the trick:

```
import static java.lang.System.out;
```

or alternatively import every static method and field using

```
import static java.lang.System.*;
```

---

Addendum by @Steve C: note that @sfussenegger said this in a comment on my Answer.

> *"Using such a static import of System.out isn't suited for more than simple run-once code."*

So please don't imagine that he (or I) think that this solution is Good Practice.

Comment: with most ide's these days it will fix it up for you anyway, in eclipse do an organise imports and it will change your java.lang.System.*; to java.lang.System.out; for you (assuming you are only using out)

Answer (score 32):

```
PrintStream out = System.out;
out.println( "hello" );
```

Answer (score 16):

@sfussenegger's answer explains how to make this work.  But I'd say *don't do it*!

Experienced Java programmers use, and expect to see

```
        System.out.println(...);
```

and not

```
        out.println(...);
```

A static import of System.out or System.err is (IMO) bad style because:

- it breaks the accepted idiom, and
- it makes it harder to track down unwanted trace prints that were added during testing and not removed.

If you find yourself doing lots of output to System.out or System.err, I think it is a better to abstract the streams into attributes, local variables or methods.  This will make your application or library more maintainable and more reusable.

(Obviously, if your Java program is a once-off thing that you intend to throw away when you have completed the current task, then maintainability is not a concern.  But the flip side is that "throw away" code is often NOT thrown away.)

Comment: I agree a missing "System." might be confusing at first look. Using local variables or attributes doesn't really change anything though, does it? Using a local `protected void println(Object o) { System.out.println(o);}` might be a good idea though as the output destination could easily be changed, say to `log.info(o)` for instance.

Comment: @sfussenegger - use of a local variable or an attribute *does* make it easier to change the destination than using System.out all over the place ... whether System.out is imported or not.

Comment: okay, that's true. But it's also possible to replace a static import of System.out by a field called out - no need to assign System.out to out. But generally, I agree with you. Using such a static import of System.out isn't suited for more than simple run-once code.

Answer (score 7):

Well, you would typically use

```
System.out.println("print something");
```

which doesn't require any imports. However, since out is a static field inside of System, you  could write use a static import like this:

```
import static java.lang.System.*;

class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        out.println("print something");
    }
}
```

Take a look at this [link](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/static-import.html). Typically you would only do this if you are using a lot of static methods from a particular class, like I use it all the time for junit asserts, and easymock.

Comment: `out` isn't a method, it's a field.

Comment: doh! Thanks for catching that. I meant to say field.

Answer (score 3):

You will have to create an object **out** first. More about this here:

```
    // write to stdout
    out = System.out;
    out.println("Test 1");
    out.close();
```

Comment: and now you don't "create" an object :)

Comment: The official java documentation uses the term "Create object" aswell as the one i guess you are referring to "instantiate" http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/java/javaOO/objectcreation.html

Comment: You don't create or instantiate an object at all. You simply copy the reference. Hence `System.out` and `out` will reference the same object, i.e. `System.out == out` will be `true`

Comment: oh, missed your "now" part :P By the way I haven't programmed java that much as you might notice

Answer (score 3):

`out` is a `PrintStream` type of static variable(object) of `System` class and `println()` is function of the `PrintStream` class.

```
class PrintStream
{
    public void println(){}    //member function
    ...
}

class System
{
    public static final PrintStream out;   //data member
    ...
}
```

That is why the static variable(object) `out` is accessed with the class name `System` which further invokes the method `println()` of it's type `PrintStream` (which is a class).

Answer (score 1):

you can see this also in sockets ...

```
PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream());

out.println("hello");
```

Answer (score 1):

simply import :

```
import static java.lang.System.*;
```

Answer (score 0):

Or simply:

```
System.out.println("Some text");
```