# Java Scanner does not wait for input

Tags: java, user-input, java.util.scanner

I have two blocks of code here. One scanner properly waits user input, and the other just blows right through it and calls `nextInt()` which returns a `NoSuchElementException`. Here is the block that works:

```
public void startGame() {
   out.println("Player1: 1 for dumb player, 2 for smart player, 3 for human player.");
   Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
   p = scan.nextInt();

   if (p == 1)
        p1 = new DumbPlayer("ONE");
   if (p == 2)
        p1 = new SmartPlayer("ONE");
   else 
       p1 = new HumanPlayer("ONE");

   out.println("Player2: 1 for dumb player, 2 for smart player, 3 for human player.");
   p = scan.nextInt();

   if (p == 1)
        p2 = new DumbPlayer("TWO");
   if (p == 2)
        p2 = new SmartPlayer("TWO");
   else 
        p2 = new HumanPlayer("TWO");

   scan.close();
```

And here is the block that does not:

```
public int findBestMove(Set<Integer> moves, Board b) {

    Set<Integer> set = new HashSet<Integer>();

    out.println("Player " +name+ ", select a column from 1-7: ");
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);  <--here it should wait for input, but does not!
    int move = scan.nextInt();   <-- NoSuchElementException
    scan.close();

    for (int x = 1; x <= 7; x++) {
        set.add(move);
        move += 7;
    }
    ....etc
```

Both of these are separate classes, and are called from a main method in yet another class. Basically `main()` calls `startGame()`, which in turn calls the `findBestMove()` method of some Player class...which is where the non-working code resides. Are there times in the program where it is not appropriate to take input? I was under the impression that anytime I wanted user input, I could use this approach. Thanks!

Comment: I see in `findBestMove` that you do a `scan.close()` which will also close the source stream - do you do the same in `startGame()`, somewhere after your `etc`?

Comment: similar issue discussed in this question, not sure if it should be closed as a dupicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7056749/scanner-issue-when-using-nextline-after-nextint

Comment: @Dennis I looked at that prior to posting, I do not think my issue is related but could be wrong.

Comment: @Andreas yes I close the scanner in both cases.

Comment: @Houdini then, this could be the second issue beside the one Denis mentioned. Dont do it - `InputStream` implements the `Closeable` interface, in which case `Scanner.close()` will also close `System.in`.  http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html

Comment: Thanks Andreas, good to know anyway. But I close the scanner after I call `nextInt()`.

Comment: do you close the scanner after `startGame`?

Comment: Yes, I included a bit more of the code to reflect that part.

Comment: do you have a global `try...catch` block anywhere? because closing a scanner and opening a new one gives me an `NoSuchElementException` on next read because stdin is closed.

Comment: I do not, I could add one but I am not sure how catching a `NoSuchElementException` would help here. Maybe I am confused about what you are saying, but in the block of code that does not work, that is the only scanner used in the class. I open it, try to grab the first `int`, then close it again.

Comment: this is confusing because nextInt can not return null, it can only throw an exception

Comment: I did not mean to imply it returns null. I fixed that, that was a poor choice of wording. It does throw an `NoSuchElementException`. I am just not sure why/how catching it would help..?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the [java.util.Scanner javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html), `Scanner.close()` closes the associated stream if this stream implements the `Closeable` interface. `java.lang.System.in` is an [InputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html), which implements the `Closeable` interface. Hence, after calling `Scanner.close()` on a `Scanner` which is associated with `System.in`, the `System.in` stream is closed and not available anymore.

The following SSCCE works for me. I have removed some code from the question which is not relevant to the actual issue. Note that with this approach, while it works, Eclipse gives me the warning `"Resource leak: 'scan' is never closed"`, so a better solution would be to use one Scanner instance only.

```
package com.example;

import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Set;
import static java.lang.System.out;

public class ScannerTest {
    int p = 0;
    String name = "Test";

    public void startGame() {
        out.println("Player1: 1 for dumb player, 2 for smart player, 3 for human player.");
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        p = scan.nextInt();

        out.println("Result1: " + p);

        out.println("Player2: 1 for dumb player, 2 for smart player, 3 for human player.");
        p = scan.nextInt();

        out.println("Result2: " + p);

        // scan.close();   // Do not close the Scanner to leave System.in open
    }

    public int findBestMove(Set<Integer> moves, Object /*Board*/ b) {
        out.println("Player " +name+ ", select a column from 1-7: ");
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        int move = scan.nextInt();
        // scan.close();   // Do not close the Scanner to leave System.in open

        out.println("Move: " + move);

        return 0;
    }

    public void run() {
        startGame();
        findBestMove(null, null);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ScannerTest st = new ScannerTest();
        st.run();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, someone else mentioned that also but they didnt say dont `close()` the one from the class that was already working! That is so odd to me, dont I open the input stream back up when I declare the new Scanner? Oh well...work now, thanks!

Comment: You probably know this, but for others maybe reading you can do a `import static java.lang.System.*` and this will allow to use just `out.println()` also.

Comment: Thanks :) I have updated the sample code. In any case, when using static imports, make sure to review the [Static Import](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/static-import.html) docs. Generally I am avoiding wildcard imports. And I am not sure if I would prefer statically importing `System.out` over explicitly noting `System.out`, especially because `java.lang.*` is implicitly imported anyway. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2504078/java-out-println-how-is-this-possible, in particular the answer from `Stephen C`.

Answer (score 6):

`nextInt()` does not discard `\n` in the stream, so the next call finds nothing. You have to skip it manually with `Scanner.skip("\n")` or `Scanner.nextLine()`

**EDIT** After figuring out that "skipping `readInt()`" meant that the code threw an exception. and with @Andreas help, here's an alternative solution. In java6 a new class [Console](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/Console.html) has been added for providing a better interface to stdin. And it returns a Reader that doesn't care how much you close it. So the following snippet works just fine:

```
    Scanner fi = new Scanner(System.console().reader());
    System.out.println(fi.nextInt());
    fi.close();

    fi = new Scanner(System.console().reader());
    System.out.println(fi.nextInt());
    fi.close();
```

Comment: @Houdini: before the call to `nextInt()`

Comment: Why do I have to do it in the second case and not the first?

Comment: I tried that but it it either says no line found, or in the case of `"\n"` it says `at java.util.Scanner.skip(Unknown Source)`.

Comment: But the problem is that there is no entering of data. The program does not wait for input. It just calls `nextInt()` without waiting for input at the console.

Comment: @Houdini: I see, sorry, I misunderstood your question.

Comment: @Houdini: see my edit about an alternative solution to your problem.

Comment: For some reason, `System.console()` is returning null, so when I try to call `console.reader()` it gives me a `NullPointerException`.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `scan.reset();` instead of `scan.close()`. `scan.close()` will throw NoSuchElementException as Denis Tulskiy said.

Comment: The exception is thrown before `scan.close()`.

Comment: Yes of course. I'd have add details. By saying scan.close() i mean by using that. Actually it throw this error when it scan for next item it found that scanner is closed. That's what i found by debugging.

Comment: Even if I leave the scanner open, I get the same result.

Answer (score 0):

I just spent about 15 minutes troubleshooting this issue and my problem was different than all of the above.

The code is fine, but I am using Sublime Text and running it in the terminal emulator inside sublime text, on windows. This prevented the scanner from actually allowing me to try to input something.

I ran the app using cmd and it worked fine. I hope this helps someone.