# java.util.Scanner: wait for input

Tags: java

I use `java.util.Scanner` to read the commands from the console.

```
try
{
    ICommand cmd = cmdReader.ReadCommand();
    cmd.Execute(conn);
}
catch(MyException ex)
{
    // print a message about unknown command
    continue;
}
```

Where `ReadCommand` is implemented as follows:

```
try (Scanner scanIn = new Scanner(System.in)) 
{
    if (!scanIn.hasNextLine()) return null;

    line_ = scanIn.nextLine();

    ICommand command = parser_.ParseCommand(line_);
    return command;
}
```

In the first iteration code works fine, I write something invalid (not a command), the code prints a warning and continues. But other iterations return `null` here `if (!scanIn.hasNextLine()) return null;` even if I write something in a console. Looks like `java.util.Scanner` doesn't see the input. Am I doing something wrong? And how then I can wait for the user input (don't want to use the cycle with `sleep`)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should not create a new `Scanner` instance each time you call `ReadCommand`. Create one and reuse it while reading input.

From the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html):

> When a Scanner is closed, it will close its input source if the source implements the Closeable interface.

So, your `System.in` stream is closed after you read the first input.

See also [Java Scanner does not wait for input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13374826/java-scanner-does-not-wait-for-input)