# Display text only for a couple seconds

Tags: java, time

I have made a simple register and login page.
After the user successfully registered or logged in, a message will display the result.

This is working fine, but I want it that the text is only displayed for a couple seconds. So after 5 seconds the text is gone.

```
        int i = ps.executeUpdate();
        if (i > 0) {
            out.print("Successfully logged in...");
            RequestDispatcher rs =    request.getRequestDispatcher("/loggedin.html");
            rs.include(request, response);
        }
```

I've searched online, but I can't find anything on how to do it.
Any tips / comments are welcome!

Comment: Does `out.print` print to a console?

Comment: Use JavaScript on the _client side_ to hide the message after a requisite number of seconds.

Comment: @Jongware http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2504078/java-out-println-how-is-this-possible

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To delete what you've printed you could print the backspace character `\b`.

So to fit your needs:

```
String s = "Successfully logged in...";
// better use System.out.print() than out.print() *
System.out.print(s);  
Thread.sleep(2000); // Wait 2 seconds

// print as backspaces as charactes printed using CommonLangs
StringUtils.repeat("\b", s.length);    

// print as backspaces as charactes printed with for loop
for (i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {
    System.out.print("\b");
}
```

Note: this doesn't work nice in Eclipse console. But works perfect in command console. See also [How to get backspace \b to work in Eclipse's console?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3095986/how-to-get-backspace-b-to-work-in-eclipses-console)

[* better use System.out.print() than out.print()](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2504115/3850595)

Comment: The `System.out.println` is a debug statement. I believe the OP is actually sending the user to a web page.